# converting audio formats using ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, electron

I want to convert wav file to mp3 audio using code below: both ffmpeg and fluent-ffmpeg are installed.

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

function decodeAudio() {
    let track = './sources/audio.wav';//your path to source file

    ffmpeg(track)
    //.setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Processing finished !');
    })
    .save('./sources/hello.mp3');//path where you want to save your file
}
```

using electron I see this error:

> An error occurred: Cannot find ffmpeg

I found a solution which says if you add this line of code the issue resolves:

```
.setFfmpegPath("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")
```

But adding this also produces this error:

> An error occurred: spawn C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe ENOENT

How to fix this?

**Edit: I used a bunch of other methods and none of them work:**

[Recording and saving mp3 files with node.js is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284244/recording-and-saving-mp3-files-with-node-js-is-impossible)

Comment: Where is ffmpeg installed? What terminal is this being run in? (if at all)

Comment: I'm using node.js and electron and I have used vs code terminal...

Comment: That’s good to know, but where is ffmpeg installed? Is it installed?

Comment: ffmpeg  is installed via npm install ffmpeg

Comment: I don't think that's the case. See _"To use this library requires that ffmpeg is already installed (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264)"_ from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

Comment: Does my comment make sense? I do not believe that the npm module `ffmpeg` also installs ffmpeg itself and requires it to be installed separately.

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg on terminal? try running ffmpeg from terminal. If it's not there you must install it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you didn't download the `ffmpeg` binary.

Install [ffmpeg-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg) with:

`npm i @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg`

Then add the following command to your code:

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
```

This will solve your problem, be happy.